# MP Android Chart barchart

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

[image]

How to date text for each bar indicator in MP Android chart.I have tried this. I'm not getting any option to set individual bar indicator settext properties

```
   private void plotData1(ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1) {
    BarDataSet set1;

    if (mChart.getData() != null && mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
        set1 = (BarDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
        set1.setValues(yVals1);
        mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "Data Set");


        set1.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);
        set1.setDrawValues(true);//give values at the top of bar

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.setFitBars(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have separate `DataSet`'s for each color.

Create `set1`, `set2`, `set3` and so on, then pass them all to `dataSets` variable.

An example `BarChartActivityMultiDataset` from the official examples can be found [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivityMultiDataset.java#L228).

Comment: Can I have a screen shot?

Comment: Download this project from github and compile it.

Comment: Hi, how to change points color when the reading cross a certain point?